# Hive load file into hive table from HDFS failing using Talend

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, talend

I am using talend 5.4 /5.5 to connect to cdh 5.1. A three node cluster

N1: CM, HIVE(all the services ),Datanode, Zookeeper.... etc
N2:RM, Datanode
N3: Datanode

when I am trying to load data from hdfs to hive table is failing where as same command from cli works just fine.

```
hive> LOAD DATA  INPATH '/user/thor/test/rev_sub.txt' INTO TABLE revenue_subs;
```

when I am running the talend job with tHiveLoad component I am getting following exception

```
[INFO ]: hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://txwlcloud1:9083
[WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - No groups available for user thor
[INFO ]: hive.metastore - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
[INFO ]: hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
[ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver - FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/user/thor/test/rev_sub.txt''
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/user/thor/test/rev_sub.txt''
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.LoadSemanticAnalyzer.applyConstraints(LoadSemanticAnalyzer.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.LoadSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(LoadSemanticAnalyzer.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:258)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:459)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:349)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:355)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:110)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:82)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.run(SQLOperation.java:129)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatement(HiveSessionImpl.java:209)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatement(CLIService.java:154)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:191)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:197)
at big_data.hivejob_0_1.HIVEJob.tHiveLoad_1Process(HIVEJob.java:375)
at big_data.hivejob_0_1.HIVEJob.runJobInTOS(HIVEJob.java:645)
at big_data.hivejob_0_1.HIVEJob.main(HIVEJob.java:504)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status; Host Details : local host is: "TXWLHPW295/10.215.206.241"; destination host is: "txwlcloud2":8020;
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:763)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1241)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
```

I am struggling with this issue for a while.

The possible reason could be
1) jdbc driver issue. Di I have to put the jdbc driver jar somewhere in the cluster? Or it is already there?
2) some thing to do with remote metastore

It will be great help if you guys could point out why the load is failing 
[image: thiveload component]

When I did `beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://10.215.204.xyz:10000 thor org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` it is returning a correct connection.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job and show the configuration of your tHiveLoad component?

Comment: thanks for your reply @ydaetskcoR. I edited the post for the thiveload configuration. Also do I have to put any jar anywhere. I did CM installation for hadoop cluster.

Comment: It looks like it has the necessary JAR's bundled with it. The error message makes it look like it's trying to go to `''/user/thor/test/rev_sub.txt''` (note the double ' rather than "). Can you check your quotes are right? Maybe also worth switching to the code view tab and Ctrl+F for `/user/thor/test/rev_sub.txt`.

Comment: I checked the values looks good. Only thing that I see are the port numbers... Also is Talend 5.4 or 5.5 works at all with cdh 5 ?